# Navigate between (form feed) sections

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions

**Background:**

- Vim `:help` states that a *section* begins after a form-feed (`^L`) in the first column **[*]**.
- In normal mode <kbd>]]</kbd> or <kbd>[[</kbd> can be used to navigate to the next or previous section (respectively).
- However, **it also stops at the next/previous `{`** in the first column.

**[*]** *I am ignoring that a section also starts at some troff macros*

**My problem:**

- I want to navigate between sections only, i.e., I want motions like <kbd>]]</kbd> and <kbd>[[</kbd> that only stop at the beginning of a section.

**Questions:**

1. Is there already a built-in motion that solves my problem?
2. Sure, I could just map some key combination to `/^<C-L><CR>`), but is there a better way? In particular, I don't like the idea of it messing with my search history.

**PS**:

- *To be honest, my **real** problem is that sometimes it is easier for **me** (and gcc!) to work with one HUGE file instead of splitting into several translation units. So I divide it into sections and I want to jump fast between sections without stopping at each function block. If you have a better approach, I would appreciate a suggestion as a comment.*
- Even though I am mainly editing C files, I guess I wouldn't care (that much) if a solution overrides the default behavior of <kbd>[[</kbd> and <kbd>]]</kbd>. Not overriding would be a plus, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one problem with `[[` and `]]` is that they kind of try to do several things at the same time. Another problem is that redefining what a *section* is is not exactly simple.

Now, `:help [[` hints at making your own mappings and there are a few default ftplugins that map `[[` and `]]` to work in a specific way. So you should probably consider something like this:

```
" in after/ftplugin/c.vim
nnoremap <buffer> [[ <Cmd>call search("^\<C-l>", 'b')<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> ]] <Cmd>call search("^\<C-l>")<CR>
```

Note the use of `:help search()`, which doesn't pollute register `/`.

If you want to use them outside of C, remove the `<buffer>` attribute and put them in your `vimrc`:

```
" in .vimrc
nnoremap [[ <Cmd>call search("^\<C-l>", 'b')<CR>
nnoremap ]] <Cmd>call search("^\<C-l>")<CR>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly without polluting register `/`. I did have to replace `<Cmd>` with  `:` but I imagine <Cmd> is a new notation not available on 8.2 (sorry I have no reputation to upvote you)